# Separate Jenkins config from build logs

Tags: jenkins

My `JENKINS_HOME` is (something like) */var/lib/jenkins*

In there, there is *jobs* directory, in it a subdirectory for each job. In each job subdirectory, you have `config.xml` plus the *builds* subdirectory.

I would like to somehow separate my config.xml from the same file structure that contains builds so that I can check them in my version control but to not clutter its view by having all the build logs that each execution writes. If I change a job config, the corresponding config.xml is changed and I can (actually in a Jenkins job) check it in my version control automatically or if I change it manually in a text editor, it gets checked out and deployed. But I don't want the builds in the version management.

Is there a way to separate just the job configs from the build logs in the filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in only backing up configs, try installing the [SCM Sync Configuration Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin). This plugin syncs with a repo each time you change either a job or the Jenkins configs, but does not keep builds.

> SCM Sync Configuration Jenkins/Hudson plugin is aimed at 2 main features :
>
> Keep sync'ed your config.xml (and other ressources) jenkins/hudson files with a SCM repository
>
> Track changes (and author) made on every file with commit messages

As a bonus you can set it to take a commit message each time you change a job, for easier restoration if necessary.

Comment: yeah -- this looks pretty awesome

Answer (score 2):

It *might* be possible, depending on your version control system.

In Git, for example, for a dir structure like this:

```
dir_in_question/
  .git/
  .gitignore
  builds/
  config.xml
```

I can prevent git from seeing any of the changes under the `builds` directory simply by adding inside `.gitignore` (which I prefer to add to the git as well) this line:

```
builds/
```

Another thing to try would be to make `builds` a symlink to a location outside the version control system, typically another filesystem. As a side effect you'd gain protection against builds filling up the jenkins' filesystem :)

Comment: I'm aware of that approach but would prefer to do a "hard" separation on disk

Comment: see updated answer